# Why are the interfaces for the mobile sites so different?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, mobile-chrome

Why are the interfaces for the mobile sites so different?

I would like to use them in the same way on each site.
In my humble opinion, the interface on stackoverflow.com is the most appropriate.

(I use Android 10 + Chrome)

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're using the "mobile site", not the "full" or "responsive" site on the lower image. Scroll to the bottom and touch "Full Site".

Comment: Thanks. For all interested: Options is on the bottom of page and is called "full site". ah.. I see you edit your post in time when I found this (thanks to you) and describe.

Comment: By the way, I haven't changed anything myself before and this begs my question: Shouldn't all pages have the same initial settings?

Comment: Each site has it own set of cookies; changing the site mode on one site won't affect the other. They aren't a setting you change in your [preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/), so it's not saved to your profile.

Comment: This is not what I was asking for. I know how cookies work. I thought about if I do not change anything at the first time I start using each page, `Why they have different initial setting ?` ... Or I miss something - maybe I just do not focus when I change them.

Comment: [su] and [so] are different sites. It doesn't matter that you've changed your site mode on [so], if you haven't on [su] it'll use the "mobile" version of the site. Clearly you changed the mode on [so] but not on [su] and why they look different. Changing it on one doesn't change it for all of them. If you haven't selected the other mode, they'll default the the "mobile" version on a mobile device.

Comment: The responsive design you see in StackOverflow is fairly new, but not everything optimized for mobile yet. I believe there are plans to eventually retire the mobile theme (the one you can see in the bottom screenshot). At that point, the responsive theme will become default.

Comment: StackOverflow also defaults to the mobile theme, but you probably switched to the full site at some point in the past.

Comment: Today all my followed sites switched again.